# The best approach for implementing a classification model that can have new classes added to it frequently?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

Let's say you are tasked with training a malware classification model, but the problem is that new malware families could be added to this model every week. for example a new malware family shows up, so you gather thousands of sample of it and you need to add this new class to your classification mode and retrain it, and this can happen every week.

So for this problem, what is the best approach to implementing it ? (In pytorch or tensorflow, doesn't matter)

Basically if you wanted to train a classification model that can have new classes added to it frequently, what is the most optimize way of implementing the model and retraining it and adding the new class to it? (The model can be a machine learning model like forest, or a deep model, this doesn't matter for me either)

Comment: You may want to lookup "class-incremental learning".

Comment: @RyanVolpi damn, never heard of that before, thank you for the suggestion will look it up. so do you think this technique is the best option for solving this problem, in a real world scenario such as malware classification, correct?

Comment: @RyanVolpi Also, what about in the case where the input feature dimension could get larger as well? for example updating the input feature vector and adding new features to it, is there any technique for this problem as well?

Comment: I don't know much about this area, just that what you described, where new classes can appear, is called class-incremental learning and there are different methods which can be used to achieve that. It seems like this is largely in the realm of research rather than something which is commonly implemented out of the box, but I'm not sure. I don't know how you would accomodate new features. Maybe google "feature incremental learning" or "attribute incremental learning" and see what comes up.